# Kubernetes import environment variables from a different .yml file

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to import environment variables from a different .yml file into the deployment file. My container requires environment variables.

*deployment.yml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: <removed>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: "TEST"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

*vars.yml*

```
NODE_ENV: TEST
```

What i'd like is to declare my variables in a seperate file and simply import them into the deployment.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds like a [helm](https://helm.sh/) use case. If your deployment were part of a helm chart/template then you could have different values files (which are yaml) and inject the values from them into the template based on your parameters at install time. Helm is a common choice for helping to [manage env-specific config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43378990/9705485).

But note that if you just want to inject an environment variable in your yaml rather than taking it from another yaml then a popular way to do [that is `envsubst`](https://serverfault.com/questions/791715/using-environment-variables-in-kubernetes-deployment-spec).